# Set auto-property's value via reflection

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I've seen various threads on how to call a property's private setter via reflection. However, what about auto-properties without a setter?

```
public class Test
{
    public string Property { get; } = "";
}
```

Is it possible to set the value of this readonly property using reflection?

- `PropertyInfo.SetMethod` returns null
- `PropertyInfo.SetValue` fails

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the value of this readonly property using reflection?

No. Those properties are backed by read-only fields. There *is* no setter; any assignments performed in the constructor write directly to the fields.

If your design makes you want to write to a read-only property via reflection, you should revisit your design :)

Comment: I'm just wondering, this is not consistent behavior (compared to C# readonly fields, which can be modified by reflection).

Comment: @D.R.: You are comparing apples to astronauts ;p

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar for `private readonly string _<>kProperty = ""; public string Property { get { return _<>kProperty; }}`. Not sure how you'd expect to call the setter when it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: calling something by reflection already circumvents design (modify private fields, etc.) so it is okay to provide the possibility to modify readonly auto properties as well. E.g., if you are writing a serializer.

Comment: @vcsjones: It could give me access to the generated private field for example (something along the lines of `prop.GetBackingField().SetValue()`).

Comment: @D.R. Well, it doesn't. The backing field is a compiler implementation detail.

Comment: @D.R.: There are plenty of uses for reflection which *don't* violate good design, e.g. only calling accessible members. You could try to work out which private field is associated with which property, but I'd really try to avoid doing that.

Comment: @JonSkeet: While this is certainly true, there are examples where circumventing the intended public API via reflection is not bad design. Which does not invalidate your point that probably most of the times something is fishy.

Comment: @D.R.: In this particular case, if you only know the name of the *property* you want to write to, but not the field, it's definitely a bad idea. The property could be implemented to read from a field with an unpredictable name. Again, I suggest you redesign if you find yourself in this position.